# Coldfusion and mySQL - seeking recommendations for general and off site backup strategy

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, backup, ms-office

CF9, Windows Server 2008 Standard, IIS7, mySQL 5.1.48 community.

I have managed to get CF to take a database mySQLdump which I was going to run as a nightly cfschedule task, with a server time based lock on the application controlled in application.cfc

That will get me a local copy, but whats the best strategy to encrypt the datadump.sql text file (and what would you use to do so for sensitive personal information)  and transfer to an off site location, cfftp?

Comment: This should probably be community wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my personal sites, I use a ColdFusion scheduled job that runs a mysqldump, and then stores the updated backup in a dropbox account. I've never bothered encrypting the backups, though that does seem like a potential hazard. What if the encrypted file becomes corrupted? Then you can't even get a partial restore from uncorrupted sections of the file.

Comment: I'm trying this approach, as it is all controllable from CF with CFFILE

Comment: I think this will suffice as dropbox encrypts to AES

Answer (score 0):

Can't you windows' scheduled tasks for the backup and EFS to encrypt it?

Comment: I found this "Moving or copying EFS files to another file system removes the encryption, but backing them up preserves the encryption."so maybe this would not do.